# Django foreign key reference name conflict

Tags: django

Location App Model:

```
class States(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.state_name

class Districts(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dis_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.dis_name

class Places(models.Model):
    district    =  models.ForeignKey(Districts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place_name  =  models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,)
    pin_no      =  models.IntegerField(null=True)
    update_time =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    create_time =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.place_name
```

Suppose, i want to map some info with District name. but in admin panel it shows all district name. (but the conflict is two states have some same district name)

i want to use this way:
working app model:

```
from location.models import States, Districts, Places
    class Info(models.Model):   
        dis_name    =  models.ForeignKey(Districts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        info_name   =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
        sort_name   =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

in Admin.py

```
class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("dis_name", "info_name", "sort_name")
    ordering = ('id',)
```

But in admin Panel it shows all district name.

So what should i do. for avoid conflict. Also if i use my own id then it removes conflict. but in admin panel it shows only all id field of all district. which is not human readable.

Example:

all i want, suppose 2 state have same district name say state Delhi and Kolkata have same district name is Darjeeling. then in admin panel 2 Darjeeling shows. then how can i sure which district comes which state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the **dis_name** unique in the **District** Class. This will prevent you from having more than one districts of the same name, even if they are in different states.

Same goes with the **place_name** in the **Places** Class.

Try with:

```
class Districts(models.Model):
  state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  dis_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
  update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self): 
     return self.dis_name +' - '+ self.state.state_name

class Places(models.Model):
  district    =  models.ForeignKey(Districts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  place_name  =  models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
  pin_no      =  models.IntegerField(null=True)
  update_time =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  create_time =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self): 
    return self.place_name + ' - ' + self.district.dis_name
```

Update : it will now show the corresponding state name with the district name in Admin panel,
And District name with Place name

Comment: yaa...its also point. But all i want, suppose 2 state have same district name say state Delhi and Kolkata have same district name is Darjeeling. then in admin panel 2 Darjeeling shows. then how can i sure which district comes which state?

Comment: May be override the __str__() to return something like : return self.dis_name + self.state

Comment: You can change __str__() method of District such that it returns the state name along with district name. I will update the answer now.

Comment: Look at the __str__ methods in the answer.